# Добавление в переменную include

Tags: php

```
ob_start();
for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
  if (empty($postrow[$i]['id'])) {break;}
  $nomer = $postrow[$i]['id'];
  $raiting = $postrow[$i]['balls'];
  $date = $postrow[$i]['date'];
  $text = $postrow[$i]['text'];
include "theme/post.php";
}
$post = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Вот такой код можно ли как то написать без использования буфера?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно, если в `theme/post.php` делать не `echo "..."`, а что-то типа `$html .= "..."` и в конце файла `return $html`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php, Example #5.

Answer (score 0):

Если честно, то не знаю, но по-моему нельзя, в переменную только можно засунуть результат подключения файла(**true/false**).